# Unable to open Chrome with specific profile on Katalon Studio

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio

I have been starting to use Katalon Studio as a primary tool for testing.

It would make my life easier for some test if when running a test Chrome would open would a specific profile, so that I can have some credentials logged in.

I used the Katalon configuration builder and it looks like this

[image: Katalon Config]

But Chrome still open as a new, nonexistent user.

Comment: Do you need Chrome credentials or do you need to login to a web app as a particular user?

Comment: @MateMrše My app works If I am logged into a certain google accounts, therefore having a profile set would make the browser remember my account.

Answer (score 1):

Katalon Studio uses ChromeDriver to handle browser, so you should set this preference in ChromeDriver.

> By default, ChromeDriver will create a new temporary profile for each
>   session. At times you may want to set special preferences or just use
>   a custom profile altogether. If the former, you can use the
>   'chrome.prefs' capability (described later below) to specify
>   preferences that will be applied after Chrome starts. If the latter,
>   you can use the user-data-dir Chrome command-line switch to tell
>   Chrome which profile to use:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile");
```